# Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript, CSS MIME type of "text/x-scss"

Tags: javascript

Hery guys,

I received a bit of code by my professor. When running the liveserver localy, the js is giving me an error in the browser terminal.

```
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript, CSS MIME type of "text/x-scss". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

I have never implemented css files in the javascript and I never used scss so I dont know how to work with this issue.
I hope someone here knows how to help me.

greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a tool like node-sass or webpack to compile the scss file into css, and then reference that in your project.

https://sass-lang.com/guide

sass is compiled to css using a compiler before being sent to the browser. Browsers don't know what to do with scss files.